# How can you use the least amount of memory when encapsulating?

Tags: java, oop, computer-science

Is there any other way other than carefully choosing the primitive data type?

Thank you so much in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

For answering your question, I presume that by "memory efficiency", you mean "using as little memory as possible"

There's no connection at all between data encapsulation and memory efficiency.

Memory efficiency depends upon several **lower-level** aspects such as how primitive values are represented in memory, how objects (including arrays) are represented in memory, how they are pooled/interned, etc. All these aspects have nothing to do with data encapsulation.

Data encapsulation happens in the **source code**, not at the lower levels. If, in your source code, you see that data and the code that manipulates the data are "tied closely" together (by some language feature such as class definition, for example), that's called data encapsulation.

Comment: I'm studying for an exam and I'm doing research, so sorry if the question was vague. Yes, I meant "using as little memory as possible". I'm being asked to answer such question, and I couldn't figure out how to respond. I understand encapsulation and OOP, but I couldn't relate them to "memory efficiency"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to understand the usage of encapsulation you should be aware about the usage of abstraction and loose coupling and as Erwin mentioned there seems to be a lack of research.